# Sass: snap bottom of a div to baseline

Tags: layout, sass, typography

I have a baseline for my content that is set in px.
I have a div which height has to resize relatively to the viewport's height.

Still, I want it to snap to the baseline:

- Top is easy, I just have to give it a padding that is a multiple of the baseline height.
- For bottom however, when the viewport's height is not a multiple of the baseline height, i logically end up with an offset.

My question is: **is there a Sass way to figure out how much this offset is?**

Here's a fiddle that illustrates the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/andinse/qc0kmnsL/

Commented out is the calculation I was imagining but I suspect I get confused with what is available when to Sass.

```
$baseline-height: 36px;
// $line-count = floor((100vh in px) / $baseline-height);
// $extra-px = (100vh in px) - $line-count * $baseline-height;
```

Still I have hope there is a workaround ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate container height, its offset or lines count on sass level, because sass doesn't know the window size (and also can't react on window resize). You would need to use css function `calc()`, which calculates on runtime, but it doesn't support modulo operator, which would be helpful. It was once supported, but only in IE, so it doesn't matter.

I see 2 solutions and none of them I find pretty, but I'll share them anyway:

a) You predefine the height / number of lines in styles and don't allow to freely resize it. You could however resize it using many media queries reading screen height. You could put this media query in sass for-loop to generate them quickly for different screen sizes (something like `$i * $line-height`). This is css only solution. This would generate a lot of output, so the final css might weight a lot and you can never cover all screen sizes this way. This is bad.

b) You modify the height using javascript by taking away extra overflow of last "line". This requires js, but works for any screen size perfectly. Don't forget to resize it on window resize, so it always fits well.

Take a look at the second solution in action: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vZbjqK, which I think is better than first one.

Comment: Great! This confirms suspicions I had. Things feel a lot clearer. Thank you!